# Removing the Great Lakes from US county-level maps in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, r-sf, r-maptools

I am using R to draw US map at county level. I downloaded the shapefile for US from [GADM](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html). The county-level shape file is "gadm36_USA_2.shp". I then used the code below to draw map:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

us2 <- st_read("<Path>\\gadm36_USA_2.shp")

mainland2 <- ggplot(data = us2) +
geom_sf(aes(fill = NAME_2), size = 0.4, color = "black") +
coord_sf(crs = st_crs(2163), 
         xlim = c(-2500000, 2500000), 
         ylim = c(-2300000, 730000)) + guides(fill = F)
```

The Great Lakes region (shown by red arrows) is plotted rather than left blank:
[image]

What I want is a figure like below, where the Great Lakes region is left blank:
[image]

How could I identify from the "gadm36_USA_2.shp" which rows correspond to the Great Lakes region so that I may delete them?

I understand there may be other ways to obtain shapefile than GADM. I believe GADM is an excellent source that provides bourndaries worldwide. I wish to take this opportunity to better acquaint myself with data downloaded from GADM.

Of course, other methods to obtain US county-level boundary data are welcome. I noted `USAboundaries` package also provide country, state, and county level coundaries, but I am having difficulties installing associated USAboundariesData package. Any idea to draw US counties in ways other than shapefile from GADM is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to remove every feature that is tagged with `Lake` in the existing records (currently 13 features). First, you need to find the lakes name in the attribute table as below:

```
# retrieving the name of lakes and excluding them from the sf 

all.names = us2$NAME_2
patterns = c("Lake", "lake")

lakes.name <- unique(grep(paste(patterns, collapse="|"), all.names, value=TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE))
#[1] "Lake and Peninsula" "Lake"               "Bear Lake"          "Lake Michigan"      "Lake Hurron"        "Lake St. Clair"    
#[7] "Lake Superior"      "Lake of the Woods"  "Red Lake"           "Lake Ontario"       "Lake Erie"          "Salt Lake"         
#[13] "Green Lake" 

`%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
us <- us2[us2$NAME_2 %notin% lakes.name, ]
```

Then you can map the remaining features:

```
mainland2 <- ggplot(data = us) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = NAME_2), size = 0.4, color = "black") +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(2163), 
           xlim = c(-2500000, 2500000), 
           ylim = c(-2300000, 730000)) + guides(fill = F)
mainland2
```

[image]

Another way (much easier but less flexible) is to map county features by excluding `Water body` values from `ENGTYPE_2` as below:

```
us <- us2[(us2$ENGTYPE_2) != "Water body",]
mainland2 <- ggplot(data = us) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = NAME_2), size = 0.4, color = "black") +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(2163), 
           xlim = c(-2500000, 2500000), 
           ylim = c(-2300000, 730000)) + guides(fill = F)
mainland2
```

[image]

Comment: Following the second method, why is Louisiana state missing?

Comment: Because for some reasons `County` in state is tagged with `Parish`. Get around it either by cleaning the data using `us2[(us2$NAME_1) == "Louisiana",]$ENGTYPE_2 <- "County"` or use `us <- us2[(us2$ENGTYPE_2) != "Water body",]`. I've change my script to the latter option.

Comment: Thank you @Majid. I have a new post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59117165/drawing-thicker-state-borders-and-thiner-county-borders-for-us-map-using-gadm-sh) on a related question. Please take a look if you have interest. Thank you again.