# Drawing thicker state borders and thiner county borders for US map using GADM shapefile

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, r-sf, r-maptools

I have an earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113457/removing-the-great-lakes-from-us-county-level-maps-in-r) on drawing US maps using shape file from [GADM](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html) while at the same time removing color mapping onto the Great Lakes region. The issue was solved following suggestion by @Majid.

Now, I further want thicker state boders and thinner county borders. I did so by plotting county-level choropleth map first and then add additional lays of non-filled state/nation-level border:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer) #for some nice color palettes

# US map downloaded from https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html

# National border
us0 <- st_read("<Path>\\gadm36_USA_0.shp")
# State border
us1 <- st_read("<Path>\\gadm36_USA_1.shp")
# County border
us2 <- st_read("<Path>\\gadm36_USA_2.shp")

# Remove the Great Lakes
# retrieving the name of lakes and excluding them from the sf 
all.names = us2$NAME_2
patterns = c("Lake", "lake")

lakes.name <- unique(grep(paste(patterns, collapse="|"), 
                     all.names, 
                     value=TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE))

# Pick the Great Lakes
lakes.name <- lakes.name[c(4, 5, 7, 10, 11)]

`%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
us2 <- us2[us2$NAME_2 %notin% lakes.name, ]

# National level
mainland0 <- ggplot(data = us0) +
    geom_sf(fill = NA, size = 0.3, color = "black") +
    coord_sf(crs = st_crs(2163), 
             xlim = c(-2500000, 2500000), 
             ylim = c(-2300000, 730000)) 

# State level
mainland1 <- ggplot(data = us1, size = 0.3, color = "black") +
    geom_sf(fill = NA) +
    coord_sf(crs = st_crs(2163), 
             xlim = c(-2500000, 2500000), 
             ylim = c(-2300000, 730000))

# County level
mainland2 <- ggplot(data = us2) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = NAME_2), size = 0.1, color = "black") +
    coord_sf(crs = st_crs(2163), 
             xlim = c(-2500000, 2500000), 
             ylim = c(-2300000, 730000))+
    guides(fill = F)

# Final plot across three levels
p <- mainland2 +
    geom_sf(data = us1, fill = NA, size = 0.3, color = "black") +
    coord_sf(crs = st_crs(2163), 
             xlim = c(-2500000, 2500000), 
             ylim = c(-2300000, 730000)) +
    geom_sf(data = us0, fill = NA, size = 0.3, color = "black") +
    coord_sf(crs = st_crs(2163), 
             xlim = c(-2500000, 2500000), 
             ylim = c(-2300000, 730000)) +
    guides(fill = F)
```

The image generated is as follows:
[image]
It can be seen that although the Great Lakes regions is no longer color coded, the state borders still exist (red arrows). I want a figure like below where states are separated by land boundaries and no state border crosses the lake region:
[image]

Any suggestion on how to achieve this is appreciated.

Comment: maybe use another US map?

Comment: @Tjebo Do you have any idea about where high-quality shapefiles for US boundaries at all three levels can be obtained apart from GADM? I wish to use shapefiles because I perfer working with sf objects to the old-fashioned `geom_polygon(data = usa, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group))` approach.

Comment: check this website out: https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf.html. And [the package `rnaturalearth`](https://docs.ropensci.org/rnaturalearth/index.html). Apparently one can very easily pull out countries/continents from the world data. You could combine it with the GADM maps - no need to only use the map data from only one source :) - e.g., first plot the states using one map data, then the counties with the other... hope this may help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even need `us0` (national border) and `us1` (State border). These already exist in `us2`. You can plot your desired output as below:

```
us0 <- sf::st_union(us2)
us1 <- us2 %>% 
           group_by(NAME_1)%>% 
           summarise()
```

and the plot you map:

```
# Final plot across three levels
p <- mainland2 +
  geom_sf(data = us1, fill = NA, size = 1.5, color = "black") +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(2163), 
           xlim = c(-2500000, 2500000), 
           ylim = c(-2300000, 730000)) +
  geom_sf(data = us0, fill = NA, size = 1.5, color = "black") +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(2163), 
           xlim = c(-2500000, 2500000), 
           ylim = c(-2300000, 730000)) +
  guides(fill = F)

p
```

[image]
Hope that helps.